# recursive xsd generates java class with Objects instead of the given Type

Tags: java, xml

So, I have an object which can contain a list of Objects of that type. I wrote an XSD which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="myNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
   <complexType name="BinModel">
      <sequence>
         <element type="string" name="min" />
         <element type="string" name="max" />
         <element type="string" name="fieldname" /> 
         <element type="int" name="defaultValue" />
         <element xmlns:ref="BinModel" name="innerBins" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
      </sequence>  
   </complexType>
   <element name="AllBins">  
      <complexType>  
         <sequence>  
            <element type="string" name="fieldnames" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element type="int" name="defaultValue"/>
            <element xmlns:type="BinModel" name="outerBins" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
         </sequence>
      </complexType>  
   </element>
</schema>
```

It produces two java classes, BinModel and AllBins respectively, but in each of those classes, even though I specify that they contain a list of type `BinModel`, it produces a List of type `Object`.

How do I generate a class which has a List of `BinModel`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized something was wrong when it took me adding `xmlns` before `type` and `ref` in order to not show errors in the editor. I looked at another xsd for a recursively defined Object somewhere else in my stupidly huge codebase to try and find a solution and discovered two things. 
1. We were defining our own namespace
2. We referenced our own objects within that namespace.

So the corrected code looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:myProject="projectNamespace" targetNamespace="myNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
  <complexType name="BinModel">
     <sequence>
        <element type="string" name="min" />
        <element type="string" name="max" />
        <element type="string" name="fieldname" /> 
        <element type="int" name="defaultValue" />
        <element type="myProject:BinModel" name="innerBins" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
     </sequence>  
  </complexType>
  <element name="AllBins">  
     <complexType>  
        <sequence>  
           <element type="string" name="fieldnames" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
           <element type="int" name="defaultValue"/>
           <element type="myProject:BinModel" name="outerBins" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
        </sequence>
     </complexType>  
   </element>
</schema>
```